The @type of the author is an "Organization", what's the damage of label author a "Person"
We always publish NewsArticles in the column of our company and label the author an Organization whose name is the company.
If a news website invites us to be the guest author or reposts our article, but they label the author a Person, what would be the effect?
Could the search engine identify that we are the author through the article content and the name of the author? What should we be worried about?

With review authors, they check that the name looks like a real person's name. Bad names can cause the loss of rich snippets.

Will it hurt the author authority of our organization?

I've not had any experience with NewsArticle. It may make it harder for Google to connect the dots that it is the same author.

I would say the only negative here would be what Tony McCreath brought up, it would make another step for Google to connect the dots versus directly attributing it as an author. If you check out author schema's page, it's pretty obvious that author is just an additional identifier and it the Person entity is the main idea.
I could be very wrong about this, but I did some research to try to find a better answer and could not come up with anything that was of worth.

Thank you so much! It explains a lot to me.
